# Why using ptrace to read memory data always returns -1?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, memory, process

The following is the code for a small example tracing program:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout<<getpid()<<endl;
    int* array = new int[100];
    memset(array, 0, 100*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        array[i]=i;
        printf("array address[%d]:%x\n",i,array+i);
    }

    int index;
    while(cin>>index){
        if(index<0||index>100)continue;
        array[index] = array[index]*10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Save the program as dummy.c. Compile and run it:
./dummy

In the output i get the array[1]'s address: 0x100046 and its value is 1.

Then, attach to dummy by using the code below:

```
unsigned long addr = 0x100046
if(ptrace(PT_ATTACH, child,NULL, NULL)==-1)
    printf("Attach Failed!");
wait(NULL);
long data = ptrace(PT_READ_D, child, (void*)addr, 0);  // after reading data always is -1, it should be 1 according dummy application
```

Comment: Is it a typo `PT_ATTACH`? It should be `PTRACE_ATTACH` Also I hope you've properly assigned the PID of `./dummy` to `child`

Comment: On linux we have PTRACE_ATTACH , but on osx,it is PT_ATTACH instead. I am sure that i have assigned the PID of ./dummy to child, i could see that my debugger became dummy's parent process after attach.

Comment: Seems that some features like the ability to read and write memory have been removed from the ptrace() call on Mac OS X .